# How to use lexicon dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

i am working on sentiment analysis in c#, I have done preprocessing, and the next part is lexicon based analysis, for which I have found English Lexicon of about 6800 word [lexicon by Professor Bing Liu](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#lexicon)  which contains two text files, one for positive and other is for negative.

I was thinking that I have to just find the each word(sentiment word) from these files that either the particular word is positive or negative. but the problem is, these files contains words without any space , without any format (means individual word can not be recognized from file ).

So how can I find the word in file? Or is there any other way through which I can work easily with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file uses `\n` as a line separator (unlike standard Windows `\r\n`).
So, just not open it with **NotePad** or alike, do it with **WordPad**.

To load the file into a collection (let it be `HashSet<String>` - you, probably, want to test if a word is *within the positive words* or not), you can use *Linq*:

```
  HashSet<String> positives = new HashSet<String>(File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\positive-words.txt")
    .Where(item => !String.isNullOrEmpty(item) && !item.StartsWith(";")));

  ....

  String testWord = ...

  if (positives.Contains(testWord)) {
    ...
  }
```

Actual file's content is

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; 
; Opinion Lexicon: Positive
...
;       frequently in social media content. 
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

a+
abound
abounds
abundance
...
zenith
zest
zippy
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the file contains one word per line, but the line endings are Unix style instead of Windows, so some editors (like Notepad) will display everything on a single line.

You can easily read the words with [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) (ignore the lines starting with `;`, those are comments).

Answer (score 1):

The file seems to contain words delimited by the line-feed character (`\n`), so the simplest approach would be to read the file using `File.ReadAllLines`.

```
var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines("negative-words.txt");
var words = new HashSet<string>(fileContents.SkipWhile(x => x.StartsWith(";") || x == String.Empty));

var containsWord = words.Contains("2-faced"); // The first valid word...
```

Putting the contents into a HashSet allows you to query the contents, you don't need a dictionary.